# Priority Queues sorting all items but the last

Tags: java, priority-queue

```
/* INPUT
Greenland
Denmark
Iceland
Finland
Sweden
Norway
*/
```

This part returns everything needed. I get them all except the last.

```
public void insert(Country item){
      System.out.println("Item receieved by pQueue: " + item.getCountryName());
      int j;
      if (nItems==0)
          pQueArray[nItems++] = item;
      else{
         for (j=nItems-1; j>=0; --j)
            if (item.getCountryName().compareTo(pQueArray[j].getCountryName()) < 0 )
               pQueArray[j+1] = pQueArray[j];
            else
               break;
         // end for
         pQueArray[j+1] = item;                                          
         nItems++;  
      }  // end else
}  // end insert()
```

It's not returning the last item properly, and I can't figure out why?

```
/* OUTPUT
Denmark
Finland
Greenland
Iceland``
Sweden
Norway */
```

Comment: why don't you use java's priority queue (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) with a custom comparator?

Comment: I strongly recommend learning how to debug this yourself as it will pay dividends longer term.  In both situations where you assign to pQueArray[...], print what's happening to the queue.  You'll quickly find out what the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the line:

`pQueArray[j+1] = item;`

this indicates that you are adding the newest item into the last position of the queue, only after you have done the processing to compare the rest of the elements.